# Qual a melhor prática para um link de "voltar página"?

Tags: php, javascript

Gostaria de saber qual a melhor prática para aquele botão/link (voltar) padrão nas aplicações?
Hoje utilizo `href="javascript:history.back();"` porém existem algumas considerações que ao longo do tempo vim me deparando, são **3 dúvidas**:

1. **INCOMPATIBILIDADE** - Já passei por situações de `javascript:history.back();` não ser compatível com alguns navegadores/versões em específico, e não funcionar, mesmo com JavaScript habilitado em cliente. Haveria alguma outra medida a ser utilizada para esta situação?
2. **OPÇÕES** - Sei que `href="javascript:history.back();"` retorna para a última página de navegação do cliente, e se precisasse voltar 2 páginas com JavaScript?
3. **PHP** - Sabendo-se que é uma linguagem server-side, mesmo assim, haveria algo em PHP para fazer esta função, nativa ou não, e não utilizar JavaScript?

*Obs.: Em relação a dúvida 3, já utilizei em alguns sistemas uma espécie de captura de página por `session`, onde um histórico era montado acompanhando a navegação, desta forma poderia direcionar um link de voltar para qualquer nível do histórico de navegação, pois as vezes preciso voltar uma, duas, ou até 3 páginas deste histórico, descontinuei esta função nos novos sistemas pois acreditei ser processamento demais desnecessário, e acabei permanecendo utilizando apenas `javascript:history.back();` e quando necessário em ocasiões específicas faço uma "gambiarra".*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Resposta 1:**

Tem este método, porém é igual ao que você usou, e não funciona em alguns navegadores.

```
<a href="javascript: history.go(-1)">Voltar</a>
```

Isso pode resolver o problema de incompatibilidade:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="history.go(-1); return false;">Voltar</a>
```

**Resposta 2:**

É só usar o mesmo comando e trocar o -1 para -2, e assim respectivamente.

```
<a href="javascript: history.go(-2)">Voltar 2 páginas no histórico</a>
```

**Resposta 3:**

Eu prefiro usar sessões assim como você disse, pois garante que não acontecerá incompatibilidades. Existe a função header() do PHP, mas pode acontecer de não funcionar em páginas protegidas "HTTPS".

```
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Comment: muito obrigado pela sua resposta, sanou todas as dúvidas. Resposta 2 funcionou perfeitamente, a questão da compatibilidade com o tempo saberemos através de feedbacks.

Comment: Parabéns pela pergunta bem organizada, está muito bem formatada.